# Can I complete an Angular FireStore Observable and be sure it loaded all documents?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says, I wonder if I can complete an Observable with data from the FireStore and be certain it loaded all data.

I have a database that is updated once a week at the most. I don't need to update my website in real time.

Before I used the FireStore, I could call a function in the `complete` section of the `subscribe` function but because the FireStore Observable never completes, this is no longer working.

I found online that I can 'complete' the Observable by unsubscribing, but can I be sure that it has loaded all data?

In case it is relevant, here are my service and a bit of code that calls the service. There may be a bit of code from other functionalities left.

**SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Track } from '../model/track';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore'

const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TrackService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
  private tracks:Observable<Track[]>;

  getTracks(){
     if (!this.tracks) {
      this.tracks = this.requestTracks().pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
    }

    return this.tracks;
  }

  private requestTracks() {
    var tracksStorage: Track[] = [];
    var tracksObservable: Observable<Track[]>;
    var tracksCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Track>;
    tracksCollection = this.afs.collection("Songs");
    tracksCollection.get().toPromise().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        tracksStorage.push(doc.data() as Track);
      })
    });

    tracksObservable = new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(tracksStorage);
    })
    return tracksObservable;
  }
}
```

**CODE THAT CALLS SERVICE**

```
this.trackSubscription = this.trackService.getTracks() 
    .subscribe(
        trackData => 
        {
            trackData.forEach(track => {
                console.log("Track data:"); // this is also not called. But probably different problem.
                console.log(track);
                track.lyrics = track.lyrics.replace(/(\\n)/g, '\n');
            });
            this.tracks = trackData as Track[]
        },
        err => {
            console.log("error in Track Component");
            console.log(err);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('Retrieving tracks completed'); // never called
            this.loadWithParams();
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `requestTracks` method you have an Observable from the `tracksCollection.get()` which you convert to a Promise, and create a new Observable with the result. This does not make much sense.

You probably want to do something like:

```
return tracksCollection.get().pipe(
   map(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.map((doc => doc.data()))
)
```

Then in the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook of your component you can:

```
this.trackSubscription.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: I copied the method from a tutorial. I tried your suggestion, but get the error that 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'. I can write it like this: `tracksCollection.get().pipe(
      map(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as Track)))` but then the code inside 'map' is not execured. (I am fairly new to Angular and still don't feel like I have the hang of Observables)

Comment: Also, I already unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy, but this is not called early enough. I want to complete the observable as soon as the data is loaded in so I can apply a filter to the data when the data is loaded. (I display part of the data on screen)

Comment: @WhiteFalcon This code should work, (with the change with map in your comment). Also there is no need to unsubscribe, as `get()` completes after request (in contrary to for example `valueChanges()`.